# Uploading an image to a website with Playwright

Tags: python, playwright

I'm trying to click the button upload an image to this website: https://prnt.sc/
But it seems like there is not even a [button], so can I even click anything? Is this even possible? Super confused.

There's lots of documentation on how to do this with selenium, but not much for Playwright unfortunately.

from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

```
with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=False, slow_mo=50)
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto("https://prnt.sc/")
    page.locator("class=uploader__browse_button").click()
```

I am not using page.click because there is no button.
(From what I can see)
I still get errors using this code.

I've gone through the websites code and found

```
<form action="https://prntscr.com/upload.php" method="post" id="fileupload">

Hopefully that helps.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `set_input_files`. Here is an example:

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.webkit.launch()
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto('https://prnt.sc/')
    # click on AGREE privacy
    page.click('button[mode="primary"]')
    # set file to form field
    page.set_input_files('input[type="file"]', 'FULL_PATH_TO_FILE_HERE')
    # wait for a link after upload
    link = page.wait_for_selector('#link-textbox', state='visible').inner_text()
    print(f'file link: {link}')
    page.screenshot(path='example.png')
    browser.close()
```

Comment: Where did you find the button[mode="primary"] ? I can not find it all?

Comment: @Jack9992 [example](https://prnt.sc/UCD9Q6ZSN_IX). it's because I don't have yours `browser_profile`(I tested from scratch). just skip it if `prnt` doesn't ask for consent.

Comment: @Danilla Ganchar I'm not sure what you mean? I'm asking how you found the button where you could click it. Because there is literally not one.

Comment: @Jack9992 do you mean `AGREE` button or `Browse images`?

Comment: @Danilla Ganchar I tried your code and it does not work:     result = next(iter(done)).result()
playwright._impl._api_types.TimeoutError: Timeout 30000ms exceeded.
=========================== logs ===========================
waiting for locator("button[mode=\"primary\"]")
============================================================

Comment: @Jack9992 I told you - just skip the line `page.click('button[mode="primary"]')` )))